# Is there a way to set function argument attribute in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, custom-attributes

I want to do something like that:

```
int[] someArray  = new int[50];

Foo([ArgumentAttribute(20)] someArray) ;

// ... `enter code here`

int Foo(int[] someArgument)
{
   //   my code ...

}
```

not sure that even possible.

Comment: No, not on an argument. You can set (and find back) attributes on parameters.

Comment: What do you want to achieve in the end?

Comment: I presume your method would need to know what to do with your hypothetical attribute's value of "20", so couldn't you just have that method accept the "20" via an additional parameter argument?

Comment: The question is `why`. That's not a good way (even if it'd be possible). Why not just `Foo(somearray.Take(20))` and make Foo accept IEnumerable<> instead.